# Text is not taking on the font style I've designated in css file

Tags: html, css

This keeps opening in sans-serif. It works everywhere else I've input except here. www.myrecruitdesk.com is the website.

Please help! :)

This is the HTML:

```
<p class="caption tp-caption sft large_bold_white">Recruitment Services</p>
```

CSS:

```
.tp-banner .tp-caption{
font-family:"Cinzel", sans-serif;
}


.tp-banner .tp-caption.large_bold_white{
font-size:50px;
line-height:60px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `.tp-banner`? Can you show that bit too.

Comment: Sure you have class on class. It just means that the element has to have **BOTH** classes.

Comment: What should the font look like?

Comment: .tp-banner p.tp-caption try that.

Comment: Let me ask the question everyone else has skipped...  Did you even hook up the font using @font-face?  Cinzel is not a system font, so if you are ONLY doing the code above, it will never work, as you are missing a very important, very major, first step.

Comment: @Michael "It works everywhere else" suggests he has.

Comment: Yes i have its a google font.  This is a bootstrap template and the css file was previously created.  I added the Cinzel font. ("its working everywhere else")

Comment: I should have added that I am a bit new to this so my knowledge or lack therein plays a strong role :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.tp-banner .tp-caption{
    font-family:"Cinzel", sans-serif;
}
```

This selector (the ".tp-banner .tp-caption" part) means that this particular rule will only affect an element with a class of tp-caption that is a descendant of an element with a class of tp-banner.

I've had a look at your website and found the element in question (the "Recruitment Services" text that is displaying in the default sans-serif font), and although that element has a class of "tp-caption" it is *not* a descendent of an element with the class "tp-banner". Thus this rule isn't in effect there.

You will probably get the result you're after if you simply change the ".tp-banner .tp-caption" selector to just ".tp-caption".

Comment: `.tp-caption` IS a descendent of `.tp-banner`.

Comment: @putvande No, it isn't. I've loaded up his website in Chrome, found the element, right-clicked and chose 'Inspect Element', and had an actual look at his document. The 'p' element in question is a descendant of a 'div.tp-banner-container', which may be what you're looking at, but there's no element with a class of 'tp-banner' in that paragraph's ancestors.

Comment: Yep. And what is the next child in `div.tp-banner-cointainer`? `<div id="revslider-26" class="tp-banner revslider-initialised tp-simpleresponsive" style="max-height: 550px; height: 550px;">`. Which is the `.tp-banner`

Comment: @putvande The next child of div.tp-banner-container will be a SIBLING of the paragraph element in question, not a DESCENDANT or ANCESTOR. They are different things. Get your terminology straight. For the paragraph to be a DESCENDANT of the tp-banner, it would have to be contained within it - it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Attached is the screenshot of the rendered dom.

Your code:

```
.tp-banner .tp-caption{
    font-family:"Cinzel", sans-serif;
}
```

This above style will apply to all .tp-caption elements which are children of .tp-banner element. But since there is no such element in the DOM, this style will not apply.

```
.tp-banner .tp-caption.large_bold_white{
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:60px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Similarly, the above code will not have any affect since there is no .tp-banner in the DOM.

I'd suggest the following code.

```
.tp-banner .tp-caption{
    font-family:"Cinzel", sans-serif;
}


.tp-caption.large_bold_white{
    font-size:50px;
    line-height:60px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```